# Join and sort Dataset Hadoop

Tags: sorting, hadoop, merge, mapreduce, dataset

I'm working project on Hadoop using mapreduce (I have 2 dataset KDD and DARPAA) and I'm looking for algorithm which can group and sort those datasets in one file.

The two dataset have this format:

```
@attribute 'urgent' real -------------- 
@Data 0,tcp,ftp_data,SF,491,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I want to merge those two dataset in one file, firstly I want to check if there is any duplication in both of file and remove duplicate line, secondly I want to group @Attribute together and @Data together).

Comment: You have an option of multiple inputs to different mapper class in the same job and then we can have a single reducer where the two files coming from two mappers can be joined

Comment: Thanks  but already i found algorithm to merge those daataset but i like to sort them in correct order 'attribute contain both attribure of 2 file' @data contain both dataa of 2 dataset
and incase if can you help me how can i check for duplicate and remove them

Comment: You can use hashmap in your code to remove the duplicates

Comment: How can i sort data ??

Comment: Data will be sorted when it moves from mapper to reducer during the shuffle and sort phase...

Comment: Can u give me algorith to do this job?

Comment: Even to sort data (no need now to remove duplicate) @Attribute (---- together) At data (together)??

Answer (score 0):

```
Map Side:
```

Two mappers has to be written one for KDD and other for DARPAA.

Get the value which is common for both KDD and DARPAA.

Make that as the output key for both the mappers

The entire input can be sent as the mapper value output.

Append the input with @data or @attribute as per the respective mappers.

```
Reduce Side:
```

Iterate through the output key of the mapper.

Compare the value that comes with the appended string(KDD or DARPAA) and do the necessary logic.

Comment: Thank you for replay but i didnt hava comom point betwen @data & @@attribute every file has there own data and attribute, how can i fix thix ? and can you send me an algorithm with 2 mapper that can do the same job like my problem ? Thank brother

Comment: I meant a common point between KDD and DARPAA ?.... Or if there is no common point between these two you want to just append one below the other?

Comment: Common point betwen darpaa KDD same file structure @@attribute ----------
----------@@data---------- ---------
I just want to group them attribute and data together ! i found algorithm i fused both file but the output file is not structured

Comment: @@attribute 'class' {'normal', 'anomaly'}
------------------------------------
------------------------------------

@@data
0,tcp,ftp_data,SF,491,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,150,25,0.17,0.03,0.17,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.05,0.00,normal
................
-------------

@@attribute class {NOTSSH,SSH}
--------------------------
--------------------------

@@data
73,73,73,0,160,160,160,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,595,17,1,73,1,160,NOTSSH

Comment: I want to have the output file like this
@@attribute 'class' {'normal', 'anomaly'}
@@attribute class {NOTSSH,SSH}
............
............
@@data 0,tcp,ftp_data,SF,491,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,‌​1.00,0.00,0.00,150,25,0.17,0.03,0.17,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.05,0.00,normal
73,73,73,0,160,160,160,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,595,17,1,73,1,160,NOTSSH

Comment: Can you send me algorithm link or project code with 2 mappers that can do this job?

Comment: I need example with 2 mapper and 2 input file and 1 reducer ! or if you can help me with an algorithm or example to solve my problem